# Hiding the title Bibliography from thesis

Tags: citing

I have completed write up of my thesis. However, there is only one problem. According to our university requirements, references are contained in a separate chapter titled "References". Moreover, references should start without the bibliography title.

However, the chapter name is ok when I run the file but the title "Bibliography" appears at the top before the references start. How can I remove it? I am unable to solve this problem after putting a lot of effort. Below are the codes and packages I have been using.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,portrait,left=1.5in,
right=1in,top=1in, bottom=1.33in, footskip=0.33in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{plain} \setlinespacing{1.66}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{Acknowledgement}
\input{mytitle.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{chapter1.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chapter2.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chapter3.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chapter4.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chapter5.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chapter6.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chapter7.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{bib.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

The reference file is a separate chapter with the following details:

```latex
\chapter{References}
\newpage

\begin{thebibliography} {99}

\bibitem{Ross-2012} Ross, B. (1977).
The development of fractional calculus 1695–1900.
\emph{Historia Mathematica}. 4(1), 75--89.

\bibitem{Euler-1738} Euler, L. (1738). 
De progressionibus transcendentibus seu quarum termini generales algebraice dari nequeunt. 
\emph{Commentarii academiae scientiarum Petropolitanae}. 36--57.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the preamble you can redefine `\bibname` with `\renewcommand\bibname{References}` and to show References as a chapter in the TOC you can use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}` in the position you want it, as a final chapter if you want it at the end of the TOC.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,portrait,left=1.5in,
right=1in,top=1in, bottom=1.33in, footskip=0.33in]{geometry}

\renewcommand\bibname{References}%to change the name 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A Chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%to display the references as a chapter in the TOC

\begin{thebibliography}{99}


\bibitem{Ross-2012} Ross, B. (1977).
The development of fractional calculus 1695–1900.
\emph{Historia Mathematica}. 4(1), 75--89.

\bibitem{Euler-1738} Euler, L. (1738). 
De progressionibus transcendentibus seu quarum termini generales algebraice dari nequeunt. 
\emph{Commentarii academiae scientiarum Petropolitanae}. 36--57.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works but not the word only "Bibliography" is replaced by References.

Comment: It works but not the word only "Bibliography" is replaced by References. I make it simpler adding \renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}  after \chapter{References} gives the output I need, i.e., Bibliography/References title from the middle of the page is disappeared and the references move/appear at the start of the page. However, when I check the similarity index on a software, unfortunately nothing else than Abstract and table of contents is scanned by plagarism detector. I obviously need to check the similarity index in abstract, table of contents and all the chapters excluding bibliography finally